# Получение почты Exchange на Perl

Tags: perl, exchange

```
use Email::Folder::Exchange;
use Email::Simple;
use Email::MIME::Attachment::Stripper;
```

К почте подключается, находит нужное письмо, а дальше ошибка:

Unquoted '"' not allowed at getMail.pl line 70.
Missing semicolon before parameter '"Единый отчет по ГП за 35 неделю.rar"' at getMail.pl line 70.

в строке 70:

```
my $tmpMsg = Email::MIME->new($message->as_string);
```

perl -c говорит что ошибок в синтаксисе нет.

Comment: Хорошо бы глянуть на весь скрипт. Можете приложить?

Comment: где то перед строкой 70 отсутствует точка с запятой, полный вариант скрипта в студию!

Comment: чуть позже выложу. Если нет; то почему perl -c выдает ОК,

Comment: `-c` - это формалистика, она не анализирует ни подключаемые модули, ни логику работы  "вообще". В рантайме и не такие плюхи бывают. И вот нутром чувствую: что-то здесь с банальным utf8 (вы, небось, под Windows?)

Comment: сервер на freebsd

Comment: и дело не с utf
на другом сервере скрипт работает, но зависает на 
my $excel = Spreadsheet::XLSX -> new ('tmp/1.xlsx');